Growth of Current in an Inductor Connected Across a Battery
When baterry is connected across inductor with no resistance in circuit, won't the current flowing through it be zero, as inductor back emf will counteract the effect of potential difference due to the battery(see the image), with same magnitude   but opposite direction ?

You need resistance otherwise the current will be infinite after transient behavior.

Yes but why does current flow when the back emf =emf of battery won't they cancel out each other

The current doesn’t flow when the switch is first closed because the current in an ideal inductor cannot change in zero time. But then the current would begin to flow. Eventually the inductor looks like a short circuit. Without resistance the current would be infinite

"but why does current flow when the back emf =emf of battery won't they cancel out each other?" Action - reaction, the reaction force by the particle is equal and opposite to the action force on the particle; still the particle can move and accelerate, why? Because the effect is on different things, force on the particle and reaction force on the thing doing the action!

@TanaySehgal Current does increase because the induced emf doesn't make the inductor work like a battery with an opposite polarity. Rather, it makes it work exactly like a resistor in the sense that it drops the voltage across it by an amount equals to the negative of the induced emf, i.e., vL=−emfinduced
. However, the voltage drop in the inductor case is dependant upon the instantaneous rate of the current increase, unlike the case with resistors. Therefore, the current can't increase to its maximum value instantaneously


My question is when baterry is connected across inductor with no
resistance in circuit won't the current flowing through it will be
zero as inductor will apply same back emf as potential difference(as
seen in image)

Yes the current would be zero, but only initially when the switch is first closed. But after the switch is closed, the current increases. Without resistance the current would continue to increase without limit.
The equation for current in a series $RL$ circuit and voltage, where $R$ can be considered the combined resistance of the coil and interconnecting wiring is, upon closing the switch, as a function of time $t$
$$i(t)=\frac{E}{R}(1-e^{-Rt/L})$$
$$v_{L}(t)=Ee^{-Rt/L}$$
As you can see, at $t=0$, $i(t)= 0$, and $v_{L}(t)=E$, as you have already indicated.
But after a long time ($t\rightarrow\infty $) the current and voltage are
$$i=\frac{E}{R}$$
$$v_{L}=0$$
If there were zero resistance $R$ in the circuit the current would continue to increase in time without limit.
So you see this is one of those situations where you must include resistance as all real conductors, with the exception of superconductors, have resistance.
Hope this helps.

Re, "after time the current would be infinite without any resistance." Maybe better to avoid that "I" word, and say that if there's no resistance, then the current will continue to increase, with no limit, forever.

@SolomonSlow Good suggestion. See edits. Thanks.


won't the current flowing through it will be zero as inductor will apply same back emf as potential difference(as seen in image) of battery but it will be in opposite direction

You are correct that induced emf and potential drop do cancel each other in the inductor, in the sense the line integral of induced electric field equals minus line integral of conservative electric field, so net motive force on current in the perfect inductor is zero. They have to cancel each other, because in a perfect conductor, which is what perfect inductor is made of, net electric field vanishes.
This does not mean current through the inductor won't increase in time; it will. Perfect inductor does not obey Ohm's law, there can be current running through the inductor even without potential drop on it, and even without any motive force on current.
Kirchhoff's second circuital law says that  current $I$ in simple circuit with inductor and voltage source obeys the equation
$$
-L\frac{dI}{dt} + \mathscr{E}_{bat} = RI,
$$
where $\mathscr{E}_{bat}$ is EMF of the battery, and $R$ is ohmic resistance of the whole circuit. If that resistance is zero (both perfect inductor and perfect voltage source have zero resistances), then
$$
-L\frac{dI}{dt} + \mathscr{E}_{bat} = 0.
$$
This equation has the solution
$$
I(t) = \frac{\mathscr{E}_{bat}}{L}t,
$$
where $t$ is time since the circuit is closed.
Thus in such ideal circuit, the current increases linearly in time, after the circuit is closed. And this happens even while net motive force on the current in the inductor is zero.
